# Why doesn't this LED work in this transistor circuit?

Tags: transistors

[image]

The Zener diode D1 has a value of 6V, both LEDs have 2mA of Ion.

When V1 is 5V, **D1** doesn't work so current should flow as **green** paths, but why LED1 is on while LED3 is off?

Comment: Maybe because the base of Q2 is half a volt (or more) more positive than the collector, and that this extra half volt (or more) is enough to make the difference in that simulation for whether it shows glowy arrows or not?

Comment: You are right...base of Q2 is 679mV and collecter is 374mV in simulation.I also find current of LED1 path is much bigger than LED3,because Q2 is conducing,is that means when NPN is used as switch,Ic >Ib and Vb >Vc?

Comment: Well I seem to understand because Q2 is conducting,base of Q2 is locked at around 0.7V,which leads to voltage drop LED3 < LED1,and for The properties of the triode itself Ib > Ic.These two aspects leads to this c condition.

Comment: "*How to modify this circuit to realize, ...*" You are changing the question. That's not fair to everyone who has answered already as it makes our answers look incomplete or stupid. Start a new question instead.

Comment: I'm so sorry for editing my quesiton, I should start a new issue instead ,thanks for pointing out my fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 mA in each led you need 4 mA in the 1 kΩ resistor which gives you a voltage drop of 4 V, and for Q2 to be on you need around 0.7 V on the Vbe so the voltage across the LED3 is around 0.3 V which isn't enough for it to turn on.

[image: exercise resolution]

Comment: Concise and concise!Tks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgOvli.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simulation results.*

1. As you expected, enough current passes through LED3 to turn Q2 hard-on. Notice that the voltage on Q2's collector has fallen to 93 mV (VM1).
2. LED1 is now turned on and R3 limits the current through it. There is 1.68 V across LED1 (VM2), and 1.77 V (VM5) on the anodes of both LEDs.
3. The base-emitter V<sub>f</sub> (forward voltage drop) results in the base voltage being 0.69 V (VM3) and this leaves only 1.08 V (VM4) for LED3. That's not enough to exceed its V<sub>f</sub> so it won't turn on.

Comment: Tks for detailed analysis for simulation.I seem to understand because Q2 is conducting,base of Q2 is locked at around 0.7V,which leads to voltage drop LED3 < LED1,and for The properties of the triode itself Ib > Ic.These two aspects leads to this c condition.

Comment: "Triode"? Transistors replaced the [triode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triode).  \$I_c \ > \ I_b \$.

Comment: Right yeah,thanks for correcting:)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems. Firstly, you share a single 1kΩ current limiting resistor between two LEDs, as shown below right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM3JT9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The red LED (D1, left) has a forward voltage lower than the green (D2, middle), and when the two LEDs are supposed to be lit, and are in parallel, the red LED will prevent the green LED from developing sufficient voltage to illuminate (D3, D4, right). This same issue can occur even between LEDs of the same colour, if they are even slightly mismatched. Therefore you must provide each LED with its own current limiting resistor.

Secondly, the base of Q2 will always be 0.7V, due to the base-emitter junction of Q2 behaving just like a diode. That means that even when Q1 is off, the cathode of your LED3 is still low, and LED3 is still illuminated. You must provide a means of permitting the collector of Q1 to rise in potential above 0.7V.

Lastly, even when Q1 is off, there will still be a tiny base current flowing via LED3 through Q2's base, causing it to always glow.

Here are the fixes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjSXmh.png)</sup>

R3a and R3b keep LED1 and LED3 independent, solving the first problem.

R4 allows Q1's collector to rise in potential, solving the second problem.

R5 acts as a low impedance path for Q2's base current, so LED3 doesn't light when Q1 is off, solving the third problem.

Also, R1 and R2 do not need to have such low resistance. R1 can be very large, since its only job is to hold Q1 off. R2 can also be significantly larger too, since Q1 has lots of current gain. By increasing those resistances, you significantly reduce the total current drawn by the circuit.

Here are currents for LED3 (blue trace) and LED1 (orange trace) as I sweep voltage source V1 from 0V to 8V:

[image]

Comment: Learned a lot about LED and transistor from your answer. Thanks for reply